# RequestDidLoad from fb api doesn't get called

Tags: xcode, facebook-graph-api

I'm experiancing the next issue:

I have 3 classes that are taking data from Facebook API and are communicating through delegating. First class takes my friends, then for each friend 2nd class calls friend's events, return them and then for each friend's event, 3rd class calls event's ID to get full event infos. This is where the issue comes in, after calling 3rd class, the fb request api gets executed (requestLoading function gets started) but it doesn't wait in that class to get reply but just jumps out of the class.

Here is the code:

```
// Class 1:
// calling friends in first class
- (void) callFriendData
{
PicShowAppDelegate* appDelegate = (PicShowAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
Facebook *facebook = appDelegate.facebook;
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
}

// receiving friends + calling friend class for each friend in which we will call events
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
NSMutableArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
NSMutableArray *tmpFriendID = [data valueForKey:@"id"];
NSMutableArray *tmpFriendName = [data valueForKey:@"name"];
for(int i=0;i<[tmpFriendID count];i++)
{
    FBFriend *fbFriend = [[FBFriend alloc]init];
    [fbFriend setDelegate:self];
    fbFriend.friendID = [tmpFriendID objectAtIndex:i];
    fbFriend.friendName = [tmpFriendName objectAtIndex:i];
    [fbFriend takeEvents];

    [friendDataArray addObject:fbFriend];
    [fbFriend release];
}
}

// class 2, friend, here I call events

- (void) takeEvents
{
PicShowAppDelegate* appDelegate = (PicShowAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
Facebook *facebook = appDelegate.facebook;
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/events",self.friendID] andDelegate:self];
}

// receiving events for certain user
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
....

// sending events back to 1st class
[[self delegate] eventsTaken:eventIDs fromFriendID:self.friendID];
}

// first class receives events for certain user, saves it to array of 
//user's events and then calls 3rd class for each event in array, to get full info
- (void) eventsTaken: (NSArray *)idEvents  fromFriendID: (NSString*) idFrenda
{

for(int i=0;i<[friendDataArray count];i++)
    if([[[friendDataArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"friendID"] isEqual:idFrenda])
        for(int j=0;j<[idEvents count];j++)
        {
            Event *event = [[Event alloc] init];
            event.eventID=[idEvents objectAtIndex:j];
            [event takeEvent];

            [event release];
        }
}

// 3rd class, event
-(void) takeEvent
{
PicShowAppDelegate* appDelegate = (PicShowAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
Facebook *facebook = appDelegate.facebook;
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.eventID] andDelegate:self];

}

// this never gets called
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assuming this object has a own Delegate.
Did you set the Facebook's delegate property to your Controller?

`[facebook setDelegate:(id)self];`

Implement the Delegate also, in your .h file's `@interface`

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <FacebookDelegate>
```

or something vaguely similar.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, thank you for trying to help and creating a post. :) I am not sure you quite understood the problem. There is no viewController here, up there in code, comments are separating 3 difference classes (friendData that calls friends, fbFriend that calls friend's events and finally class event that takes full info of each event). By [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@".." andDelegate:self]; by this andDelegate:self (at least I think) we set the delegate. So self means data should return to the calling class. In the calling class, function requestDidLoad is implented and so the data should come..

Comment: But in my program data just doesn't arrive. It says requestLoading 1000 times and goes out of class event then.. :/ And yes, all classes got implemented <FacebookDelegate> protocols. :)

Comment: Do you need to authenticate with facebook somehow? And is the location you are authenticating to (e.g. The website) correct? Just guessing here now.. :(

Comment: Hm, don't think so, because earlier calls finish normally and bring results. Only the last (event class) layer fails, to get full event infos. Friend calls and friend's events calls gets executed normally. :S